# Provide a bond pricing differential equation and invoke Feynman-Kac

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Grateful for any assistance.

Consider the process:
$dZ=r(t)Z\,dt$ ,  where $r(t)$ is stochastic and $Z=Z(r,t;T)$ is a zero coupon bond. Provide a bond pricing differential equation and invoke Feynman-Kac to show the solution requires the risk neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$:

$$
Z(r,t;T)=\mathbb{E_Q}\left[\exp\left({-\int^T_tr(s)\,ds}  \right)\right].
$$

Everything I read suggests write the PDE associated with $Z(r,t;T)$, integrate it and then take the expected value. I am stuck however on the first step as $dZ$ does not look like the usual Brownian motion with drift and diffusion? Thanks

Comment: The notation you used suggests that $r(t)$ is not stochastic. Is that how the problem is written?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely how my problem is formulated. Thanks

Comment: I think I have worked out the dZ process. It evolves like money in the bank. i.e. the change in the value of the zero coupon bond (dZ) in a timestep (dt) is equivalent to earning interest at a rate r(t) over time. Since we don't know r(t) it is stochastic, I think.

Comment: Usually I see fixed income pricing done with a drift-diffusion process on the interest rate, not on the bond. The price of the bond has to approach par as it reaches maturity, so it's not a random walk.